# How to force Gigabyte motherboard to boot in the backup bios by shorting pins on the bios chip?

Tags: motherboard, bios

I have a bios update for my motherboard on the Gigabyte website and flashed it using qflash (because I had problems with my old bios).

After the update reached 100% my pc turned off automatically, which is normal. However, it did not turn back on automatically.

After 10 minutes I pressed the power button and the fan started spinning, with the led on in the motherboard; but after a couple seconds my computer turned itself back off.

How can I force my motherboard to boot in b_bios, which is the backup bios, by shorting the pins on the bios chip? Is his the best solution, or is there another way to recover my PC?

For reference, my motherboard is a `Gigabyte B150M D3H DDR4 REV 1`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You said that you had problems with your old BIOS, but then you flashed a new BIOS. It sounds like you have a corrupted BIOS, and that is why you are asking to boot back into the backup BIOS.

Anyway, here is how you boot back into the backup BIOS:

**Method 1**

1. Switch off your computer
2. Hold the power button until your computer starts and shuts down again
3. Press the power button again, your backup BIOS should kick in now and should re-flash the backup BIOS if there's anything wrong with the new one.

**Method 2**

1. Switch off your computer
2. Hold the power AND the reset button for about 10 sec, then release.
3. It should boot into the backup BIOS now.

**Method 3**

Only use this if nothing else works.

1. Short out pins 1 and 6 on the main BIOS chip by attaching a jumper to both the pins (pin #1 should be marked with a red dot or whatever)
2. Tell a friend to press the power on button while you do this, because right now you are holding the jumper on the pins
3. Remove the jumper you're holding between pins 1 and 6 as soon as you hear a beep.
4. Backup BIOS should boot now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but  i don't know how to connect bios pins. What should i use. And if i press or hold the power button same thing happens pc starts and shuts down after 1 sec. I have tried method 1 and 2. (i googled before asking this question. And found all 3 methods).

Comment: Technically you can use anything as a jumper cable, even a paper clip, but watch out because don't touch the metal with your finger since your finger is a conductor. Ideally, you would use an actual jumper cable, that  you can get off ebay or other places. The point is you need to "short" out the pins. This means attaching a conductive material like metal to both pins, this will short it out.

Comment: My bios chip doesnt have any red dot or any. So, i can't find which is pin 1 or 8.

Comment: upload a picture of your motherboard showing the pins and I will take a look.

Comment: Here is the<a href="http://www.gigabyte.com/fileupload/product/2/5491/20150827102037_big.png">image</a>.

Comment: Image link http://www.gigabyte.com/fileupload/product/2/5491/20150827102037_big.png

Comment: Can you give me a close up picture to the pins that need to be shorted? Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much but yesterday i have sent my pc to the service centre it will take about 2-15 working days

Comment: I'm glad you have found a solution, best of luck to you! :)

Comment: see also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhI-t5lh_38

Comment: Mine was a B85M board. Tried method 3 several times that were hours apart and worked just about to give up. Marks on the BIOS was `MXIC MX25L6473E M2I-10G`. Pin 1 was CS# (Chip Select) and pin 6 was SCLK (Clock Input) per datasheet. Anyone attempting to short the pins should check the datasheet for the chip beforehand and make sure not mess up with the power supply pin or may get shocked electrically and emotionally.