# How to access to gigabyte bios backup

Tags: bios, backup

So recently I updated my motherboard bios "X570 UD"
To a more recent one of "punch technologies" But it came damaged or something similar, it wouldn't let me access my Windows profile, I got an error on a blue screen with a text warning that it couldn't be accessed.

**I made a backup of the old bios but I don't know how to use the backup**.

Comment: https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/X570-UD-rev-10/support#support-dl-bios here are all the bios versions, the program Efiflash flashes the BIOS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force Gigabyte motherboard to boot in the backup bios by shorting pins on the bios chip?](https://superuser.com/questions/1141050/how-to-force-gigabyte-motherboard-to-boot-in-the-backup-bios-by-shorting-pins-on)